# How can I pause a BackgroundWorker? Or something similar

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, cancellation, request-cancelling

I was using a `BackgroundWorker` to download some web sites by calling `WebClient.DownloadString` inside a loop. I wanted the option for the user to cancel in the middle of downloading stuff, so I called `CancelAsync` whenever I found that `CancellationPending` was on in the middle of the loop.

But now I noticed that the function `DownloadString` kinda freezes sometimes, so I decided to use `DownloadStringAsync` instead (all this inside the other thread created with `BackgroundWorker`). And since I don't want to rewrite my whole code by having to exit the loop and the function after calling `DownloadStringAsync`, I made a while loop right after calling it that does nothing but check for a variable `bool Stop` that I turn true either when the `DownloadStringCompleted` event handler is called or when the user request to cancel the operation.

Now, the weird thing is that it works fine on the debug version; but on the release one, the program freezes in the while loop like if it were the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me you are busy-waiting with a while loop. You should use event signaling instead, eg. a WaitHandle. A busy-waiting loop in release mode might very well consume all your cpu, giving a feeling of a freeze.

Signal the WaitHandle in DownloadStringCompleted or if the user cancels the download.

Check the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) on the WaitHandle class. There's also an example there.

Comment: Pause/Resume loop in Background worker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359058/pause-resume-loop-in-background-worker

Answer (score 0):

Send your while loop that is checking for the cancelation to sleep for a short while (some ms). This well free up the CPU runtime for other threads and processes.

Comment: Busy waiting is bad practice.

Comment: I know and I didn't know that there was something like a WaitHandle in C#/.Net (always new things to learn :-)), but sometimes polling is the only solution and then one should make sure that the process polling only checks once and then gives up the CPU time (in Linux its the yield() function) given to the thread/process by the OS.

Comment: The WaitHandles can also be used with a timeout, so that would prevent polling :) (And I have used my share of busy waiting until I got wiser.. hehe)

Answer (score 0):

nice topic, i used
In my background worker process a double while

```
 int icounter = 1;
 while (icounter < SomeListInventory.Count)
            {
                while (pauseWorker == false)
                { 
                    //-----------------------
                    //DO SOME WORK
                        icounter++;
                    //-----------------------
                }
            }
```

And i have a button pause, that when i press it, pauseWorker (Global variable or property) becomes true and loops in the first while only, without increasing the icounter, and when i make the pauseworker=false again the process continues