# Pause/Resume loop in Background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a loop in Background worker in a Winform Application.

I Just used this [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924275/pause-and-resume-a-for-loop-in-c-sharp) but it won't resume after the Pause.

In the main Class I use this

`System.Threading.ManualResetEvent _busy = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);`

Then in My Start Click I wrote this:

```
      if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Busy"); //Just For Debugg
                _busy.Set();
                Start_Back.Text = "Pause";
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(tempCicle);   
            }
            else
            {
                _busy.Reset();
                Start_Back.Text = "Resume";
            }

            btnStop.Enabled = true;
```

Then in backgroundworker doWork I wrote this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
     m_addTab addTabsInvoke = addTabUrl2;
      Invoke(addTabsInvoke, "http://www.google.com");
        foreach (something)
                {
                    _busy.WaitOne();

                    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (tabs.InvokeRequired)
                        {
    ......
    ......
```

I can't understand why pause works while resume doesn't work. Did I wrong something?

Comment: Reset() will cause the DoWork method to hang, blocking on the WaitOne() call.  The opposite of a resume, I'd say.  Hard to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want resume and pause a loop in background worker. I just followed the code that i linked.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924275/pause-and-resume-a-for-loop-in-c-sharp

Comment: Maybe i understood the problem. After that i click on Pause , i will never do Set() again cause isBusy will always be true so it will never do If code...i think

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you told us what you're trying to accomplish and we can recommend a solution for you. If you are trying to update progress from a background worker, you should look at [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My best guess for what you want:

```
void ResumeWorker() {
     // Start the worker if it isn't running
     if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(tempCicle);  
     // Unblock the worker 
     _busy.Set();
}

void PauseWorker() {
    // Block the worker
    _busy.Reset();
}

void CancelWorker() {
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) {
        // Set CancellationPending property to true
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        // Unblock worker so it can see that
        _busy.Set();
    }
}
```